# minimax - connect four - c - recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I try to implement the minimax-algorithm into my connect-four game.
I want to implement it with recursion. However I think i dont explore the whole gametree with my function:

```
for(i=0;i<COLS;i++) {
    if(can_throw(c, i) == 0) {
        throw(f, i);
        if((is_winner(c) == 0) && (is_board_full(f) == 0)) { //no winner, board not full
            minimax(f);
        }
        else if(is_winner(c) == 1) { //there is a winner
            evaluate_turn();
            undo_turn();
        }
        else if(is_winner(c) == 0 && (is_board_full(f) == 1)) { //no winner, board full
            evaluate_turn();
            undo_turn();
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone has a solution how to explore the whole gametree with recursion?
The evaluation is just 1 for win, 0 for draw, -1 for loss.

I`m not sure either whats the best way to compare the evaluations against each other, to have the right values on the "top-level" without introducing  a datastructure (which would exceed memory). Does someone know how to do that either?

Comment: are you asking us to write the functions for you?

Comment: Conceptionally, `if(can_throw(c, i) == 0) {
        throw(f, i);` looks wrong --> if can throw is false, then throw.  Is this code's intent?

Comment: i get what u mean - can_throw == 0 means that the row is not full. Should have commented this either. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yeah, but that's backwards; that's wrong.  `can_throw` returning false (`0`) should mean you can't throw. You should change `can_throw`. "Oh I forgot to tell you that pressing the brake pedal releases the brakes in this model" just doesn't cut it.